# How does recursion work in this case?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, quicksort

```
var arr = [7,3,28,8,9,13,1500,45];

function qsort(a) {
    if (a.length == 0) return [];

    var left = [], right = [], pivot = a[0];

    for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] < pivot ? left.push(a[i]) : right.push(a[i]);
    }

    return qsort(left).concat(pivot, qsort(right));
}

alert(qsort(arr));
```

This routine sorts array by using Quicksort algorithm.
The Question is how will the base case `if (a.length == 0) return [];` ever be true to stop the recursion?

Answer (score 6):

```
if (a.length == 0) return [];
```

when length is 0 it stop.

Comment: @BinaryTox1n: because it directly answers the OP's question: "The Question is what makes recursion to stop, to exit here to avoid infinite iterations??". If that is not what the OP wants to know the question should be reworded. The real question should be: Why does Nathan Romano's identical answer have -1 vote?

Comment: @saus Because it should. There are multiple other answers who provide detailed explainations (if you read the comments, that is what the OP really wants) yet this answer with no real content has more upvotes than all others combined. It doesn't "directly answer the question" if the OP still doesn't understand whats going on.

Comment: @BinaryTox1n: It directly answers the question that was asked, even if that's not what the OP actually wants. "What makes the recursion stop?" sounds more to me (and the upvoters) like "Where is the base case?" than "Why is the input smaller on each recursion?" As I said, perhaps the question needs to be changed to avoid confusion. I don't have edit privileges, but I've submitted a change for review.

Comment: @BinaryTox1n: Fact is that often the first and the shortest answer gets the most votes, sometimes even if it isn't correct (not referring to this answer). Just the way it is.

Answer (score 6):

The array passed to the recursive call is always at least one smaller than what was passed into the function, because it won't contain the pivot element.  So you eventually hit the base case where a.length == 0, and return without recursing.

Comment: but when qsort(left) is invoked, it will execute pivot = a[0]; Will it?? Why not??

Comment: @DrStrangeLove - if you are still confused after the various explanations I suggest you either work through it manually, on paper (perhaps with a shorter starting array), or use a JavaScript debugger to step through the whole thing and check the lengths of the arrays being passed with each recursive call, or maybe just put a whole bunch of console.log() statements in and check the output. You'll see that with gradually smaller and smaller arrays being passed around eventually a zero-length array will stop the recursion.

Comment: @DrStrangeLove: When `a.length == 0`, there is not `a[0]` item. When `a.length == 0`, there's a `return` statement, so the rest of the function *does not execute*. Think of it as an `if/else` statement. If `a.length == 0`, return, otherwise run the rest of the code in the function. If you rewrite the function to use `if/else` it may seem more clear.

Comment: @patrick dw: i understand that. i meant when a.length != 0; will it execute pivot = a[0];?? why?? or why not??

Comment: @DrStrangeLove: Yes it will. If `a.length` is not `0`, that means there's at least one item in the Array. So that first item (at index `0`) will be assigned to `pivot`, and the remaining items will be assigned to the `left` and `right` arrays (as they compare to the `pivot`). So if the Array had a `.length` of `10` to start, then the first item is assigned to `pivot`, and the remaining `9` items are split up between `left` and `right`. The same thing will happen when `left` and `right` are sent to `pivot`. The first item will become the `pivot`, and the remaining will be divided up.

Comment: Second to last sentence, I meant *" The same thing will happen when `left` and `right` are sent to **`qsort()`**"*. Not `pivot`.

Answer (score 6):

Just remember:

- `pivot` is the first item in the Array
- `left` is items lower than `pivot`
- `right` is items higher than `pivot`

So the first time you have `qsort( [7,3,28,8,9,13,1500,45] )`:

```
left=[3]      pivot=7      right=[28,8,9,13,1500,45]
```

---

Now `qsort()` is recursively called on both the `left` and `right` Arrays.

Let's just look at `left`, so `qsort( [3] )`:

```
left=[]       pivot=3        right=[]
```

---

Once again, `qsort()` is recursively called on the `left` and `right` Arrays.

Again, let's just look at `left`, so `qsort( [] )`:

And what is the very first thing `qsort()` does?

```
if (a.length == 0) return [];
```

---

If it received an empty Array (which it did here), it just returns an empty Array, halting execution on that branch.

Because each invocation of `qsort()` pops the first item off the Array, each time `qsort()` is invoked, the Array it received gets shorter and shorter, until an empty Array is sent to `qsort()`.

---

### Another way to think of it:

The potentially confusing part is that `qsort()` knocks the first item off and then divides the rest of the Array into 2 parts.

Just imagine if it *didn't* split the Array, but just knocked the first item off.

This function doesn't really do anything but recursively call itself with the remainder of the Array.

```
function recursive_test( arr ) {
    if( arr.length === 0 ) { return []; } // empty Array? Just return.

    var first_item = arr.shift();      // first item in the Array (the head)
                            // now "arr" represents the remainder (the tail)

    return recursive_test( arr );  // Just send the "tail" to the same function
                                   //   so the next time through, the Array is 
}                                  //   shorter by 1
```

So when you invoke the function, the following happens:

```
var array = [5,2,8,3,6,9,0];  // original Array

recursive_test( array );  

// the first time it gets the full Array
// [5,2,8,3,6,9,0]

// but then it pops the first item off, and calls itself with the "tail" of the Array
// [2,8,3,6,9,0]

// again it calls itself, just with the "tail"
// [8,3,6,9,0]

// and again, and again, and again...
// [3,6,9,0]
// [6,9,0]
// [9,0]
// [0]
// []

// The last time it gets an empty Array. 
// The function sees that it gets an empty Array, and just returns, 
//   halting the recursion
```

The exact same thing is happening in your function, except that instead of a "head" and a "tail" with the "tail" being passed on recursively, you get a "head" (`pivot`) and a "tail" that gets split into 2 Arrays (`left` and `right`).

Both parts of the tail are sent to a recursive calls, getting their heads popped off, splitting the remainder, and doing it again until there's nothing left.

Answer (score 2):

In quick-sort, you're taking a divde and conquer approach -- rather than solving the whole problem at once, you divide the problem in half, solve each half, then merge the answers back together.

To solve each half of the problem, we simply call quick-sort recursively -- ie, We divide the problem in half again until we get to something we can't divide it any further...  That's handled by this line:

```
if (a.length == 0) return [];
```

So now that we've divided it in half a bunch of times and solved all those problems, we can merge them back together.

this line:

```
return qsort(left).concat(pivot, qsort(right));
```

says "Take the left sub-problem and the right sub-problem, stick them together, and that's my answer".

This sort of bubbles up to the top, sticking all the different sub arrays together and generating an array with the answer.

It's a little more complicated than that, but that's the recursive bit anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Posting this as a separate answer since it takes up a bit of room.

Here's a representation of the recursive calls. I changed `left` to `lo`, `right` to `hi`, and `pivot` to `piv` in order to save room.

While the concatenation may be hard to follow, it shows the flow fairly well.

```
                          qsort( [7,3,28,8,9,13,1500,45] )
                                           |
             |-----------------------------v-----------------------------------|
             | lo=[3]                   piv=7           hi=[28,8,9,13,1500,45] |
                 |                                                  |
                 |                                                  |
                 v                                                  v
            qsort( [3] )                             qsort( [28,8,9,13,1500,45] )
                 |                                                  |
   |-------------v------------|       |-----------------------------v--------------------------------------------|
   | lo=[]    piv=3     hi=[] |       | lo=[8,9,13]               piv=28                            hi=[1500,45] |
       |                 |                   |                                                              |
       |                 |                   |                                                              |
       v                 v                   v                                                              v
  qsort( [] )       qsort( [] )       qsort( [8,9,13] )                                           qsort( [1500,45] )
                                             |                                                              |
                                |------------v---------------|                                |-------------v--------------|
                                | lo=[]   piv=8    hi=[9,13] |                                | lo=[45]   piv=1500   hi=[] |
                                    |                  |                                            |                  |
                                    |                  |                                            |                  |
                                    v                  v                                            v                  v
                                qsort( [] )      qsort( [9,13] )                              qsort( [45] )       qsort( [] )
                                                       |                                            |  
                                         |-------------v -----------|                  |------------v-------------|
                                         | lo=[]    piv=9   hi=[13] |                  | lo=[]    piv=45    hi=[] |
                                            |                  |                           |                  |
                                            |                  |                           |                  |
                                            v                  v                           v                  v
                                       qsort( [] )        qsort( [13] )                qsort( [] )         qsort( [] )
                                                               |           
                                                   |-----------v-------------|
                                                   | lo=[]   piv=13    hi=[] |          
                                                       |                 |          
                                                       |                 |    
                                                       v                 v   
                                                  qsort( [] )        qsort( [] )
```

To follow the concatenation, basically start at the root, follow the `lo` as far and deep as you can, until you can't go any deeper.

Then backtrack taking note of the most recent `piv` you passed, and follow its `hi` branch followed by all the `lo` branches you can do.

Repeat this process, always giving favor to the `lo` branches, and taking note of the `piv` as you pass them while backtracking.

This will give you the fully sorted Array.

Answer (score 0):

This would cause the stop of recursion

```
if (a.length == 0) return [];
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be the line `if (a.length == 0) return [];`. Recursion stops once you pass an empty array to the function. Since your input array is divided by two for each recursion, this is bound to happen.

A bottom level example:

`+` is concatenation

`["a","b","c"]` ends up being

`[] + [a] + [] + [b] + [] + [c] + []`
b is the pivot, and a (left) and c (right) both go through another iteration of quicksort. this adds a `[]` to each side of both, and then concatenates all three together.

Comment: but why in the end does it return right result instead of empty array??

Comment: @DrStrangeLove Because it concatenates an empty array onto the end of the result array. This, of course, does not actually alter the array.

Comment: in this call: qsort(left).concat(pivot, qsort(right)); what is the sequence of executions?? What runs after what??